# At places sys.stdin.readline works and at places only input() works

Tags: python-3.x

I used sys.stdin.readline() and input() in the same code. Worked both times. Below are the codes:

```
import sys
print('how much was your meal')
price = int(input())
print('how much would you like to tip in percentage')
tip = int(input())
tipamount = price * (tip/100)
print('your tip amount is %s' %tipamount + 'dollars')
```

Second code:

```
#import sys
#price = int(sys.stdin.readline())
#print('how much would you like to tip in percentage')
#tip = int(sys.stdin.readline())
#tipamount = price * (tip/100)
#print('your tip amount is %s' %tipamount + 'dollars')
```

But when I used sys.stdin.readline in the following code, it didn't work. Instead input() worked. Could someone please explain why sys.stdin.readline worked in the first code but not in this one?

```
import sys
print('are you looking to study digital media in australia?')
answer = str(sys.stdin.read())
if answer == 'yes':
print('Deakin University has one of the best Digital Science Program!')
```

Comment: Did you end you input with EOF? It else `.read` will try to keep reading https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase note you use `.read` with no arguments, so it will wait until it gets EOF, `readline` reads until it reaches a newline

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So I used ctrl+D and it did move on to the next line. So did it by using sys.stdin.readline. But in both cases it failed to move on to the 'if' argument

Comment: How do you know that? Did you `print(repr(answer))`? Any basic debugging at all?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I will reply to this soon when I have grasped some concepts as I am fairly new to python